# In mongodb , what will happen if I issue sh.shardCollection multiple times with the same shard key?

Tags: mongodb

While creating indexes, duplicate index requests are ignored. Is there a similar guarantee for sharding collection with the same shard key ? (asking this because the command to create a  shard is issued in a piece of java code which could execute many times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only execute shardCollection command once per collection. The further commands on same collection will throw error. In code you can check for if collection is already sharded and then decide to shard the collection

Comment: Thanks, any pointers on show to check if a collection is already sharded from the mongodb java driver ?

Comment: CommandResult stats = collection.getStats(); this command will help you figure out if collection is shared or not. I am not much of a Java guy and I am using node.js with mongoDB

Comment: Thanks. Found out that db.<collection>.getShardDistribution() will also give list of shards for the collection.